# Reversing the order of a MariaDB recursive CTE

Tags: recursion, mariadb, common-table-expression

I have a MariaDB 10.2.8 database which I am using to store the results of a crawl of all files beneath a particular root directory. So a file (in the `file` table) has a parent directory (in the `directory` table). This parent directory may have its own parents and so on up to the original point at which the directory crawl began.

So if I did a crawl from `/home`, the file `/home/tim/projects/foo/bar.py` would have a parent directory `foo`, which would have a parent directory `projects` and so on. `/home` (the root of the crawl) would have a `null` parent.

I've got the following recursive CTE:

```
with recursive tree as (
    select id, name, parent from directory where id = 
    (select parent from file where id = @FileID)
    union 
    select d.id, d.name, d.parent from directory d, tree t
    where t.parent = d.id
) select name from tree;
```

which (as expected) returns the results in order, where `@FileID` is the primary key of the file. e.g.

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 17
Server version: 10.2.8-MariaDB-10.2.8+maria~jessie-log mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> use inventory;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
MariaDB [inventory]> with recursive tree as (
    -> select id, name, parent from directory where id =
    -> (select parent from file where id = 3790)
    -> union
    -> select d.id, d.name, d.parent from directory d, tree t
    -> where t.parent = d.id
    -> ) select name from tree;
+----------+
| name     |
+----------+
| b8       |
| objects  |
| .git     |
| fresnel  |
| Projects |
| metatron |
+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [inventory]> Bye
tim@merlin:~$
```

So in this case, file ID 3790 corresponds a file in the directory `/metatron/Projects/fresnel/.git/objects/b8` (`/metatron` is, of course, the root of the crawl).

Is there a reliable way of reversing the order of the output (as I want to concatentate it together to produce the full path). I can `order by id` but this doesn't feel reliable as even though I know, in this case, that children will have a higher ID than their parents I can't guarantee this will always be the case in every circumstance I want to use a CTE.

Answer (score -2):

```
(
     your-current-query
) ORDER BY ...;
```

(If you have trouble with that, then stick `SELECT ...` in front, too.